# Cannot resolve symbol T in Scala 2.12

Tags: scala, generics

The `org.apache.parquet.column.statistics.Statistics` class is defined in Java as `public abstract class Statistics<T extends Comparable<T>>`. I am writing a function in Scala that takes `Statistics` as an input parameter. The declaration I came up with is below which is giving me the error `Cannot resolve symbol T`. I understand the issue but can't quite figure out how to fix it.

```
def getMinMaxAsString(stats: Statistics[T <: Comparable[T]] ): (Option[String], Option[String]) = {
          (Some(""),Some(""))
}
```

Comment: How about `def getMinMaxAsString[T <: Comparable[T]](stats: Statistics[T])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to introduce a [type parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html) `T` to a function, you have to first declare it between square brackets after the name of the function

```scala
def functionName[A,B](param: A): B = ???
                 ^ ^
```

`A` and `B` are two type paremeters. Also you can add [upper type bounds](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/upper-type-bounds.html) and [lower type bounds](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/lower-type-bounds.html).

```scala
class UpperTypeBound
def functionName[T <: UpperTypeBound](param: T) = ???

class LowerTypeBound
def functionName[T >: LowerTypeBound](param: T) = ???
```

In your case, you have something like

```scala
case class Comparable[T]()
case class Statistics[T <: Comparable[T]]()
```

to make your method have a type parameter `T` with an upper bound type of `Comparable[T]`, you should have to do something like

```scala
  def getMinMaxAsString[T <: Comparable[T]](stats: Statistics[T]): (Option[String], Option[String]) = {
    (Some(""), Some(""))
  }
```

As you can see, the type parameter is defined before the parameters values and you can type the paremeter values with the type parameter you declare

Comment: In your last piece of code, the upper bound is redundant with the one of `Statistics`. If you don't use the type somewhere else in the method and need the upper bound, it's not necessary.

Comment: @GaëlJ not sure if I got your point. If I remove the upper bound of `getMinMaxAsString[T <: Comparable[T]]` I will get the error `type arguments [T] do not conform to class Statistics's type parameter bounds [T <: Comparable[T]]` because `Statistics` has the type parameter `[T <: Comparable[T]]`. Maybe I should put all that code together?

Comment: My bad, I thought it was unnecessary and the upper bound was "propagated" automatically or checked only at instantiation place. Nevermind.